# How do I access certain keys in a Perl nested hash?

Tags: perl, hash

I dumped a data structure:

```
print Dumper($bobo->{'issues'});
```

and got:

```
$VAR1 = {
    '155' => {
        'name' => 'Gender',
        'url_name' => 'gender'
    }
};
```

How can I extract `155`?

How about if I have:

```
$VAR1 = {
    '155' => {'name' => 'Gender',  'url_name' => 'gender'},
    '11'  => {'name' => 'Toddler', 'url_name' => 'toddler'},
    '30'  => {'name' => 'Lolo',    'url_name' => 'lolo'}
};
```

I want to print **one** key, i.e. the first or second to see the value of the key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, based on the example you posted, the hash looks like this:

```
$bobo = {
    issues => {
        155 => {
            name     => 'Gender',
            url_name => 'gender',
        },
    },
};
```

'`155`' is a key in your example code.  To extract a key, you would use `keys`.

`my @keys = keys %{$bobo->{issues}};`

But to get the value that `155` indexes, you could say:

`my $val = $bobo->{issues}{155};`

Then `$val` would contain a hashref that looks like this:

```
{
    name     => 'Gender',
    url_name => 'gender'
}
```

Have a look at `perldoc perlreftut`.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. actually i just want to print one key at a time. see my updated question part2.

Comment: got it! just have to go through the array  @keys

Answer (score 1):

It is a key in the hash referenced by `$bobo->{'issues'}`. So you would iterate through

```
keys %{$bobo->{'issues'}}
```

to find it.